# How can I split a string in Python based on and or params effeciently?

Tags: python, string, split

I have input string like ((display_name contain 'Fw-1111' or display_name contain 'P1') and site_name contain 'device').

Input can have any combination of filter in any order.

I want to fetch each filter separately based on type. e.g. all filter on display_name  should come together as single Input like (display_name contain 'Fw-1111' or display_name contain 'P1').

I used split string to parse it and get the filters separately. Although I was able to do but the code is clumsy. I think there should be a better way to achieve this in Python. Please let me know an efficient way to achieve this.

This is my sample clumsy code:

```
column_search =  ((display_name contain 'Fw-1111' or display_name
contain 'P1') and site_name contain 'device')

col_search_list = column_search.split('and')
if 'display_name' in col_search_list[0]:
     policy_filter = col_search_list[0]
elif 'site_name' in col_search_list[0]:
     site_filter = col_search_list[0]
if len(col_search_list) >1:
     if 'display_name' in col_search_list[1]:
         policy_filter = col_search_list[1]
     elif 'site_name' in col_search_list[1]:
         site_filter = col_search_list[1]
```

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Please explain better. You've mentioned `column_search` but not declared it beforehand.

Comment: @RobKwasowski Sorry, forgot to mention column_search is Input string mentioned above ((display_name contain 'Fw-1111' or display_name contain 'P1') and site_name contain 'device').

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Loop over "col_search_list":

```
col_search_list = column_search.split('and')
for term in col_search_list:
    if 'display_name' in term:
         policy_filter = term
    elif 'site_name' in term:
         site_filter = term
```

Comment: This gives unnecessary single bracket. ( for first term and ) for last term. How can this be taken care even with multiple brackets in input

Comment: I have no idea what you meant, please show an example of input.

Comment: Input : ((display_name contain 'Fw-1111' or display_name contain 'P1') and site_name contain 'device')
Output: 
policy_filter : ((display_name contain 'Fw-1111' or display_name contain 'P1')  site_filter: site_name contain 'device')

Expected Output:
policy_filter : (display_name contain 'Fw-1111' or display_name contain 'P1')  site_filter: (site_name contain 'device')

Comment: Delete them off 'term' if necessary: `if term[0] == "(": term = term[1:-1]`

Comment: Thanks. I used policy_filter.translate(None, '()') to remove any occurrence of brackets

Comment: Can this be done generically?
I mean now in the input string I have display_name and site_name. If I have 4 more params. How can it be done effectively?
I do not want to add if else blovk 4 more times.